# Hosting Oracle PLSQL Cartridge on Microsoft IIS

Tags: oracle, iis

I hardly got in touch with the Oracle PLSQL Cartridge so far, and where I did, I found an Apache web server in place. I wonder whether it is possible to host the cartridge on a Microsoft IIS instead as well. Google wasn't really promising, so just to make sure... Feel free to say **NO!!**. If you happen to say yes, so much the better! :-)

Comment: To the one who voted to close: Would this question better fit on serverfault.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the Thoth Gateway fit the bill ?

http://code.google.com/p/thoth-gateway/

Comment: Hi Gary, this sounds like it's not supported out-of-the-box? (If mod_plsql is the same as the "PL/SQL Cartridge", then yes, they say it's not supported)

Comment: @chiccodoro: The Thoth Gateway is an open source project not affiliated with or supported by Oracle in any way. That said, it does implement almost all of the features of mod_plsql (and a few that mod_plsql doesn't have), it performs well, and it's stable and reliable. And did I mention it's free... :-)